# Issue in TDS 5.7 with sitecore 9.3

Tags: tds

I have project set up with Sitecore 9.3, TDS 5.7 and Glass Mapper 5.6.160.

I am getting below issue when I click on `Test` button on `BUILD` tab on the TDS project after setting Sitecore web folder and Sitecore deploy folder. I have checked the checkbox for the access guid.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

```
Connection Test Failure: Failed to complete test.
Exception System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Method not found: 'Void Sitecore.Data.Serialization.ItemReference..ctor(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)'. 
   ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Sitecore.Data.Serialization.ItemReference..ctor(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)'.
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Service.TdsService.<>c__DisplayClass2.<GetItem>b__0()
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Service.TDSExecutionContext.Wrap[T](Func`1 func)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Service.TdsService.GetItem(String key, String sitecoreDatabase, String accessGuid, String itemIdOrPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Service.TdsService.GetItem(String key, String sitecoreDatabase, String accessGuid, String itemIdOrPath) (FaultException):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade to the latest TDS version. If you check the [change log](https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Download/TDS-Classic) you need at least 6.0.0.13 for Sitecore 9.3

Comment: Thanks Mark!, FYI, on machine i have sitecore 8.1 update 3 application running . if i upgrade TDS.. will it cause any issue with existing one or not? i am using visual studio 2017. When will i install  SitecoreTDS_VS2017 as per upgrade perspective, i assume  installing sitecoreTDS_VS2017 will not cause any issue.. do i have to buy something for licensing point of view . or existing licensing will work.. i just have to install sitecoretds_vs2017.. and i should be ok.. does not think about licensing.?

Comment: If you also need to use some old instance then yes, TDS might complain about versions. Either you'll need to also upgrade TDS for those other instance, or you could use VS 2017 for TDS 5.x and VS 2019 for TDS 6.x. TDS license are valid for all versions.

Comment: SitecoreTDS_VS2017  with version TDS 6.0.0.13 does not  provide backward compatibility for sitecore 8.1 . if backward compatibility is there with  TDS 6.0.0.13.. then i should be able to use both instance on the same machine with VS2017

Comment: TDS supports Sitecore 7.0+ https://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/tds/chapter2.html#system-requirements

Comment: I upgraded TDS, I did not see any issue. It is working fine. Thanks Mark!!